# LCR meter weird datasheet

Tags: lcr

I have a LCR meter. In the datasheet there is a measurement frequency given for the inductance measurement. But not for the measurement of the capacitance. Is the frequency for the capacitance measurement not important?

Comment: No, the frequency for capacitance is important too. I would assume it's the same as for inductance just out of convenience of design, but I can't say that for certain.

Comment: It is possible that capacitance is measured "at DC", using the exponential rise time method. Capacitance measured "at DC" will probably fairly accurately reflect capacitance up to 10 or maybe 50MHz, so unless you want to extrapolate to a very hign frequency, measurement at DC will be usually be good enough.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Particularly poor dielectrics may have very different responses at even relatively low frequencies though, so it may be unsuitable for measuring capacitors with particularly lossy dielectrics.

Comment: @Hearth. Fair enough.

Comment: A weird LCD might be variable frequency with a fixed  R per decade in a feedback oscillator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both capacitors and inductors have a performance that can vary with frequency, the sensitivity of capacitors to frequency is slight to non-existent. The sensitivity of inductors is serious to pathological.

A good LCR meter will not simply tell you what the measurement frequency is, but will measure at several different frequencies, to allow you to see what's happening to the measurement.

Capacitors

At the sort of frequency common LCR meters use (kHz, 10s of kHz), the geometry/inductance of 'most' capacitors is negligible.

The frequency dependent dielectric relaxation effects of most plastics are completely negligible, and you would be hard-pressed to measure the effects of electrolytics in a simple LCR meter.

Inductors

These are generally wound on a magnetic core.

If you use a frequency that's too low, the core will saturate, and the measured inductance will change by orders of magnitude.

If you use a frequency that's too high, the core will become very lossy, which may create a significant reading error, depending on the method the LCR meter uses.